# Nokia Places API? Is there a detailed description of search results? And how heavity is this api used?

Tags: here-api

Has anyone worked with Nokia places API.  I am not seeing a lot of activity on the community forum?  I was curious about the level of use that it has in the industry?  here is my question:

1) What is meaning of having []?  What could have been specified here?
2) What is the unit of distance? is it meters? feet?
3) how accurate is vicinity?  is this the real address of starbucks or just an approximation?
   if approx. how accurate is it?

{ Starbucks } { position: [ 40.74864 , -73.98841 ] distance: 270 title: Starbucks averageRating: 0.0 category: { Coffee/Tea } icon: http://download.vcdn.nokia.com/p/d/places2/icons/categories/23.icon vicinity: 906 6th Ave ↵
New York City NY 10001 ↵
USA having: [ ] type: urn:nlp-types:place href: http://demo.places.nlp.nokia.com/places/v1/places/840dr5ru-846b0ffe4ec64caf83a11bafd4b5a5b9;context=Zmxvdy1pZD04ZWY4YTY4Ni1iN2RhLTVhYTEtOGM0Mi1kNjYxNTM0NGEyNThfMTM2MzAzNjEyNDY1Nl8wXzQ3NTEmcmFuaz0x?app_id=myappid&app_code=myappcode id: 840dr5ru-846b0ffe4ec64caf83a11bafd4b5a5b9 } ,

Answer (score 1):

> ...Nokia places API. ... the level of use that it has in the industry?

The RESTful [places API](http://developer.here.com/places) is used as a back-end service by [here.com](http://here.com), so a places request is made to the service whenever a user requires more details about a place. As regards third party usage I haven't got the details. Personally I see using a place service as a good way of easily adding value to an app without much effort - say for example your organization has data about country-side walks - you could easily add value to your app by finding *"places to eat and drink"* near to your route(s) without needing to become an expert on pubs and restaurants - which would be outside of your domain of expertise.

> 1) What is meaning of having []? What could have been specified here?

I can't see **having []** as being documented in the current release documentation - I believe it is a place holder for further information - if you read the definition of the   [extensible contract](http://developer.here.com/docs/places/topics/extensible-api-contract.html) you will see that additional  elements may be added to the feed at any time - your best bet here is to ignore the attribute for now.

> 2) What is the unit of distance? is it meters? feet?

Distances are in metres - you can use a function like the one below to convert

```
function calculateDistance(distance){
        if (metricMeasurements){
                if (distance < 1000){
                        return "" + distance + " m.";
                } else {
                        return "" + Math.floor(distance/100)/10 + " km.";
                }
        } else {
                if (distance < 1610){
                        return "" + Math.floor(distance/1.0936) + " yards";
                } else {
                        return "" + Math.floor(distance/160.934)/10 + " miles";
                }
        }
}
```

> 3) how accurate is vicinity? is this the real address of starbucks
>   or just an approximation? if approx. how accurate is it?

**Vicinity** is described in the documentation [here](http://developer.here.com/docs/places/topics/vicinity.html) - it can be used to filter out more distant places if necessary. For an individual place the **address** element holds the full address details, with the **address.text** holding the formatted address. Regarding the specific place query - [here.com](http://here.com/usa/new-york-city/coffee-tea/starbucks--840dr5ru-846b0ffe4ec64caf83a11bafd4b5a5b9) has a Starbucks at 906 6th Ave. This can be confirmed by another source [here](http://www.gps-data-team.com/where/Starbucks_New_York_-_Manhattan_Mall).